# Login (Cannot retrieve data from database)

Tags: android, sqlite, authentication

I'm beginner in Android programming, I'm trying to make the login function. This system will be accessed by two users which are admin and users. The admin just need to enter the "admin" for the username and password to access the system. However, the users needs to register their account before login the system.

I think there is no problem with the registration. However, when I try to login the account, it says that the username and password are not matching. I think it cannot retrieve the data from the database. Please help me check the register and login function code. Thank you

MainActivity.java

```
public void onclickLogin(View view) {
Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Please wait....", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
txtusername = Username.getText().toString();
txtpassword = Password.getText().toString();
DatabaseOperations dop = new DatabaseOperations(this, null, null, 1);
Cursor CR = dop.getInformation(dop);
CR.moveToFirst();
boolean login_status = false;
String NAME = "";
if (txtusername.equals("Admin") && (txtpassword).equals("Admin")) {
    Intent in = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AdminMenu.class);
    startActivity(in);
} else {
    do {
        if (txtusername.equals(CR.getColumnIndex(TableData.TableInfo.USERNAME)) && (txtpassword.equals(CR.getColumnIndex(TableData.TableInfo.USERPASS)))) {
            login_status = true;
            NAME = CR.getString(CR.getColumnIndex(TableData.TableInfo.USERNAME));
        }
    } while (CR.moveToNext());
    if (login_status) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Login Success....\n Welcome " + NAME, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity.this,UserMenu.class);
        Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("username",NAME);
        i.putExtras(bundle);
        startActivity(i);
        finish();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Login Failed...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

DatabaseOperations.java

```
public Cursor getInformation(DatabaseOperations dob)
{
SQLiteDatabase database=dob.getReadableDatabase();
String[] columns={TableInfo.USERNAME,TableInfo.USERPASS};
Cursor cr=database.query(TableInfo.TABLE_NAME,columns,null,null,null,null,null);
return cr;
}

public void putInformation(Account account) {
ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
cv.put(TableInfo.USERNAME, account.get_username());
cv.put(TableInfo.USERPASS, account.get_password());
cv.put(TableInfo.USERPHONE, account.get_Phone());
cv.put(TableInfo.USEREMAIL, account.get_Email());
cv.put(TableInfo.USERCARPLATE1, account.get_CarPlate1());
cv.put(TableInfo.USERFULLNAME, account.get_FullName());
cv.put(TableInfo.USERIC, account.get_IdentityCard());
SQLiteDatabase SQ = this.getWritableDatabase();
SQ.insert(TableInfo.TABLE_NAME, null, cv);
Log.d("Database operations", "One row inserted");
SQ.close();
}
```

RegisterPage.java

```
 public void onclickRegistering(View view)
    {
            registerusername=RegisterUsername.getText().toString();
            registerpassword=RegisterPassword.getText().toString();
            conpassword=ConPassword.getText().toString();
            phone=Phone.getText().toString();
            email=Email.getText().toString();
            identitycard=IdentityCard.getText().toString();
            fullname=FullName.getText().toString();
            carplate=CarPlate.getText().toString();
            if(!(registerpassword.equals(conpassword)))
            {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Passwords are not matching",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                RegisterUsername.setText("");
                RegisterPassword.setText("");
                ConPassword.setText("");
                Phone.setText("");
                Email.setText("");
                IdentityCard.setText("");
                FullName.setText("");
                CarPlate.setText("");
            }
            else
            {
                DatabaseOperations db=new DatabaseOperations(this,null,null,1);
                Account user=new Account(registerusername,registerpassword,Integer.parseInt(phone),email,Integer.parseInt(identitycard),fullname,carplate);
                db.putInformation(user);
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Register Successfully...",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Intent in=new Intent(register_page.this,MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(in);
                finish();
            }

        }
```

Comment: where you getting data from database

Comment: sorry I forgot to add the register function just now

Comment: Try logging in with name `0` and password `1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the below snippet you are trying to compare both username and password retrieved from the database with username alone - hope that might be the reason you are getting the error.

```
do {
    if (txtusername.equals(CR.getColumnIndex(TableData.TableInfo.USERNAME)) && (txtpassword.equals(CR.getColumnIndex(TableData.TableInfo.USERPASS)))) {
        login_status = true;
        NAME = CR.getString(CR.getColumnIndex(TableData.TableInfo.USERNAME));
    }
} while (CR.moveToNext());
```

refer the below link
[Using SQlite to validate Logins in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5202775/using-sqlite-to-validate-logins-in-android)